# How to default user state to logged in user Firebase and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just implemented authentication into my web app with React and Firebase. It works great but I realized that, for every page change or refresh, it first defaults the state to a null user. The AuthChangeListener immediately fires and detects that something is logged in and rerenders the screen. I get this is how React works but how can I default my current user state to the currently logged in user. It looks like a quick flicker as of now.

```
export default class Router extends Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user:null
    }
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
  }
  authListener()
  {
    // fetch current user
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          user:user
        });
      }
      else {
        this.setState({
          user:null
        });
      }
   });
  }
  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.authListener();
  }

render()
  {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/donate" component = {() => <Donate user={this.state.user} />}/>
          <Route exact path="/" component = {() => <Donate user={this.state.user} />}/>
          <Route exact path="/news" component = {News}/>
          <Route exact path="/about" component = {About}/>
          <Route exact path="/auth" component = {() => <Auth user={this.state.user} login={this.login} logout={this.logout}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/funded" component = {Funded}/>
          <Route exact path="/contact" component = {Contact}/>
          <Route path="*" component={Error} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: don't know about your react framework, but basically, you serve up HTML that shows a loader animation of some sort that becomes hidden/stops once `.onAuthStateChanged` resolves. Or just maintain a white screen and toggle it off `.onAuthStateChanged` resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I remember running into something like this. Unfortunately `onAuthStateChanged` acts when the session state changes (user logs in/out) but it doesn't tell you if there is an active session.

The only way I found to deal with it is check the `currentUser` property with a repeating timer and set a state property to false until the result comes back `null` or with the current session, after a number tries. While the timer runs I had an overlay and a rotating timer in the screen to let the user know that the app is working. If the result is null, no user session, show the login form. If the active session comes back, show the respective component.

```js
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = { sessionChecks: 0 };
  this.auth = firebase.auth();
  this.checkActiveUser = this.checkActiveUser.bind(this);
}

checkActiveUser(){
  const loggedUser = this.auth.currentUser;
  // set this to the amount of tries you want
  if( !loggedUser && this.state.sessionChecks < 3) {
    setTimeout( () => {
      // no user session, check again
      this.setState({ sessionChecks: ( sessionChecks + 1 ) });
      this.checkActiveUser();
    }, 500); // change the time to what you want
  } else if(loggedUser) {
    // there is an active user, run your code here
  }
}
```

Another option, that still requires to check the user session with a timer is to use the `reload` method of the `currentUser`, which returns a promise that you can use in an async code:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User?authuser=0#reload

---

**EDIT**

In order to check for a user session just once the solution I came up with was to  create a component with all the routes and add that component in the main app file.

This is the main app file (index.js)

```
const App = => <Provider store={appStore}>
  <Router>
    <Routes />
  </Router>
</Provider>;
```

`App` gets passed to ReactDOM's render method. Router is BrowserRouter imported like this: `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";`. And routes is a component with all the routes. That component is mounted just once in the lifecycle of the app.

Here is the `<Routes />` component (at least the relevant part of it):

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    sessionChecks: 0,
    currentUser: null
  };
  this.renderRoute = this.renderRoute.bind(this);
  this.checkActiveUser = this.checkActiveUser.bind(this);
  this.authSession = firebase.auth();
}

checkActiveUser() {
  const { sessionChecks } = this.state;
  const loggedUser = this.authSession.currentUser;
  // check for the loggedUser
  if ( !loggedUser && sessionChecks < 3 ) {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.setState({ sessionChecks: ( sessionChecks + 1 ) });
        this.checkActiveUser();
      },
      500
    );
  } else if ( loggedUser ){
    // in this check there is a logged user
    // update the component's state, this will force a render
    // and the corresponding component will be rendered
    this.setState({ currentUser: true });
  }
}

renderRoute(component){
  // if the current user is null means we're still checking
  // so we check strictly true
  if ( this.state.currentUser === true ) {
    // the check is complete and there's an active user, show the component
    return component;
  } else if ( !this.state.currentUser ) {
    // the check is complete and there isn't an active user
    // show a login component 
    return <LoginComponent />;
  }
}

render(){
  return <div>
    <Route path="/" exact render={ () => this.renderRoute(<DashboardComponent />) } />
    <Route path="/tags" render={ () => this.renderRoute(<TagsComponent />) } />
    <Route path="/posts" render={ () => this.renderRoute(<PostsComponent />) } />
    <Route path="/programs" render={ () => this.renderRoute(<ProgramsComponent />) } />
  </div>;
}
```

Now here instead of just showing the login component all the time, while the code checks, you can show an overlay with a spinner and a message over the login component and when the checks are complete, independent if there's an active session or not, hide that overlay and show the rendered component, either the login component or the one for the specific route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It just seems ugly from a user experience standpoint. Since I have login in the Navbar to check to see if the user is logged in, it will flash every time I refresh or change pages.

Comment: Well, this is just a part of the entire code I ended up using. Keep in mind that at the very top of the code it checks if  `loggedUser` is falsy. You could turn that into a boolean and add it to redux or the component's state to prevent a glitch on routes changes. Also I use this code in the base routes component, one that's never unmounted through the app's life-cycle. You just need to find where to add the code and won't have flashes or anything like that.

Comment: Would I need any middleware with Redux to be able to persist that user state on route changes?

Comment: Nope, just put it in your top routing component. Normally routes are added into a single component that renders just once. I'll update my answer to reflect that code.

Comment: Thank you @Rodrigo for the helpful responses. I was able to resolve this with a mix of two solutions. 

 1. Push user to redux
 2. Instead of using <a> tag to change route I used Link tag

I think the a tag was refreshing the entire app. This would cause that flicker while the AuthState was trying to get the current user. The Link tag allowed me to just render subcomponents of the Router. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yep, when using react router aways use the `<Link>` component, otherwise is basically pointless to have it in the first place... as you already found out :D